# Custom deserialization with Gson

Tags: java, gson

I've been trying to improve my code on this but don't know how, the json i get is this:

```
{   
"name": "Jhon",
"lastName": "Smith",
"clothes": {
    "gender":"male",
    "Shirt": {
        "id": 113608,
        "name": "Green Shirt",
        "size": "Large"
    },
    "Pants": {
        "id": 115801,
        "name": "Black Leather Pants",
        "size": "Large"
       }
    }
}
```

The way it works so far is having both Shirt and Pants classes but as they are identical im trying to use just one class that will get both of them.I have no say in how the json is generated so have to work with it as it comes.

This are my classes:

**Class Person**

```
public class Person{
    private String lastName;
    private String name;
    private Clothes clothes;
}
```

**Class Clothes**

```
public class Clothes{
    private Shirt Shirt;
    private Pants pants;
    private String gender;
}
```

**Class Shirt**

```
public class Shirt{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String size;
}
```

Pants is the same as shirt, the thing is that i don't want my code to break if/when they decide to add another piece of clothing so i'm trying to do something like this

**Class Clothes**

```
public class Clothes{
    private List<Something> clothList;
    private String gender;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have.

Comment: I think the solution is in writing custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 2 separate classes (`Shirt` and `Pants`) simply use one class - let's say `Cloth`. Tried it like that and worked fine:

**Person class:**

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29550820;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private Clothes clothes;
}
```

**Clothes class:**

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29550820;

public class Clothes {
    private String gender;
    private Cloth Shirt;
    private Cloth Pants;        
}
```

**Cloth class:**

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29550820;

public class Cloth {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String size;
}
```

After Building these classes I tried it directly in a little main class which results in a perfectly fine deserialized.

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Person person = g.fromJson("{\"name\":\"Jhon\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\",\"clothes\":{\"gender\":\"male\",\"Shirt\":{\"id\":113608,\"name\":\"Green Shirt\",\"size\":\"Large\"},\"Pants\":{\"id\":115801,\"name\":\"Black Leather Pants\",\"size\":\"Large\"}}}", Person.class);
```

Didn't use `@Expose` here or `@SerializedName("something")` because it wasn't needed.

Hope it helps you out - otherwise please explain your problem in more detail and I will try to help you.

**----------- Update ------------**

Okay normally it's quite easy to cast a Json as you have it there in an normal `Object` - but the thing is inside the map (`clothes`) you have also a normal `String` value. For this purpose I would suggest you to enable the `Gson` functionality `@Expose` I will tell you why this would be a good idea later.

Let's start:
I removed the `Clothes` class with a `Map<String, Object>` which `Gson` can easily deserialize - problem here was that the we also have the gender inside that map. I modified the Person class which now works like this:

**Person v2:**

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29550820;

public class Person {
    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("clothes")
    private Map<String, Object> clothesWrapper;

    public String getGender() {
        return clothesWrapper.get("gender").toString();
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.clothesWrapper.put("gender", gender);
    }
}
```

Now we can already map the `gender` as `String` and modify it with the getter and setter - still have the map up there which contains `Object`s. Next thing we don't want the `Map<String, Object>` - for deserializing and serialization it's totally fine - but for working with the `Cloth`s itself - it's stupid so let's get rid of it with the easiest way:

We modify our Person class like this:

**Person v3:**

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29550820;

public class Person {
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @Expose
    private String lastName;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("clothes")
    private Map<String, Object> clothesWrapper;

    private Map<String, Cloth> clothes;

    public String getGender() {
        return clothesWrapper.get("gender").toString();
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.clothesWrapper.put("gender", gender);
    }

    public Map<String, Cloth> getClothes() {
        if (clothes == null) {
            Gson g = new Gson();
            clothes = new HashMap<String, Cloth>();
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : clothesWrapper.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals("gender")) {
                    continue;
                }
                String helper = g.toJson(entry.getValue());
                Cloth cloth = g.fromJson(helper, Cloth.class);
                clothes.put(entry.getKey(), cloth);
            }
        }
        return clothes;
    }
}
```

As you can see we now indirectly cast all the `Cloth`es - we have to do this like that because it's the easiest way to get all the `LinkedTreeMap` to a `Cloth`-`Object` without running into a `ClassCastException`. As you can see we now have a `Map<String,Object> clothesWrapper` which let Gson Parse the object (can't find a better name - sorry) and the `Map<String, Cloth> clothes` map without Expose. Now you also need to setup the Gson with the enableExpose option which works like this:

(Using the Person v3 Class here - simply debug into it - works like a charm)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson g = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        Person person = g.fromJson("{\"name\":\"Jhon\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\",\"clothes\":{\"gender\":\"male\",\"Shirt\":{\"id\":113608,\"name\":\"Green Shirt\",\"size\":\"Large\"},\"Pants\":{\"id\":115801,\"name\":\"Black Leather Pants\",\"size\":\"Large\"}}}", Person.class);
        System.out.println(person.getClothes());
        System.out.println(person.getGender());
    }
}
```

You can find all classes in this [github repository](https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q29550820)

Comment: A I see :) I will try to achieve that - give me some time :)

Comment: Found a solution - now cooking up the answer for you up there